# Why can't I tab into CSS3 checkboxes?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I've been following tutorial on styling checkboxes using only CSS3 and here's what I came up with:

DEMO:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/jaoe0azx

Checkboxes are styled just fine - but when I tab through form controls -> checkbox is being skipped. Any advice why?

HTML:

```
<form role="form" id="login_form" data-mode="login">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="ue">Username or email:</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" name="ue" id="ue" placeholder="" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="password">Password:</label>
       <input type="password" class="form-control input-lg" name="password" id="password" placeholder="" />
    </div>
    <div>
          <input id="rememberme" type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="1" class="checkbox_1" tabindex="0" />
          <label for="rememberme" class="checkbox_1" tabindex="0">remember me</label>
    </div>
    <div id="auth_area_login_button">
        <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary">
            Login
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
 @import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css');    

#login_form{padding:20px;}

label.checkbox_1 {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin: 0px;
}

label.checkbox_1:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
label.checkbox_1:hover:before{border-color:#66afe9;}
input[type=checkbox].checkbox_1 {
    display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox].checkbox_1:checked + label.checkbox_1:before {
    content: "\2713";
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #A0A0A0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

EDIT 1:

seems to work in firefox, but not in chrome...

Comment: Hi, please show some relevant code in here. Thanks! ([Here's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it/126000#126000) why)

Comment: Seems to gain the focus after pressing tab on the password field, at least on latest Firefox (26.0), but I can't check it with spacebar, as in a "normal" checkbox.

Comment: hmm. yeah - works in firefox, not chrome...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the real checkbox is hide with `display:none` you can't focus it but you can also don't hide the element just make it be under the `:before` of the label:

```
input[type=checkbox].checkbox_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  margin-top: 3px;
}
```

Check this http://cssdeck.com/labs/pl4ljry7

<sub>Tested in Chrome</sub>

Comment: I tried checking your link focus not working in that

Comment: Hi @khush, old question but I checked and still works. Maybe visually you are not noticing that since there is styles lacking for the focus state. I've added some style to that so you can see it working https://cssdeck.com/labs/pl4ljry7 .... Click on password then TAB and you should see it highlitng, usually this are toggled by pressing space. Give it a try and let me know

Comment: Checkbox should be focused after tab is clicked from password field, I tried this just now and it is not working on your link - to focus on checkbox user has to click twice when current focus is on password field

Answer (score 16):

Input must be accessible to receive focus. It works in chrome/chromium if you add following lines.

```
input[type=checkbox].checkbox_1 {
    opacity: 0;
}
input[type=checkbox].checkbox_1:focus + label.checkbox_1:before {    
    border: 1px solid #66afe9;
}
```

Comment: I went with this method but set outline instead of border. `&:focus + label::before { outline: auto; outline-color: -webkit-focus-ring-color; }`

Answer (score 3):

Because, it is not a checkbox.

Look at the css:

```
input[type=checkbox].checkbox_1 {
    display: none;
}
```

The checkbox is actually hidden. So, you will not be able to focus it. The stylized square and checkmark shown are through the `:before` pseudo element on `label`. Pseudo-elements can't be focused. Nor can the labels.

Comment: Hide it behind the label so the default tabIndex is maintained.

Comment: A `<label/>` can be focused if it has `tabindex="0"` or some other `tabindex` setting.

Comment: @binki: No. You can't. See my another answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27568825/1355315

Comment: OK, you can in IE-11 and modern Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I came up with a Jquery solution when the CSS solution didn't work for me, and thought others might find this helpful.  I wrapped the input in a div with the desired tabindex value and the class "checkbox-add-tabindex".  Then, using Jquery, I transferred the tabindex from the div to the input.

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox-add-tabindex" tabindex="10">
    <input id="rememberme" type="checkbox" name="rememberme" value="1" class="checkbox_1" tabindex="0" />
     <label for="rememberme" class="checkbox_1" tabindex="0">remember me</label>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(".checkbox-add-tabindex").focus(
    function () {
        var tabval = $(this).prop("tabindex");
        $(this).removeAttr("tabindex");
        $(this).children(":first").attr("tabindex", tabval);
        $(this).children(":first").focus();
     })
```

Comment: I was able to make mine tabbable by adding the tabindex='0' as you show, but cannot select/deselect with the spacebar?