# tabIndex doesn't make a label focusable using Tab key

Tags: html

I'm trying to replace checkbox/radio inputs with icons. For this, I need to hide the original checkbox/radio. The problem is, I also want the form to properly support keyboard input, i.e. let the input remain focusable by `Tab` key and selectable using `Spacebar`. Since I'm hiding the input, it cannot be focused, so instead, I'm trying to make its `<label>` focusable.

[This documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#tabindex) and various other sources led me to believe I can do that using `tabindex` attribute (corresponding to `HTMLElement.tabIndex` property). However, when I try to assign `tabindex` to my label, it remains as unfocused as ever, however much I try to `Tab` to it.

**Why doesn't `tabindex` make the label focusable?**

The following snippet demonstrates the issue. If you focus the input with your mouse and try focusing the label using `Tab`, it doesn't work (it focuses the following `<span>` with `tabindex` instead).

```js
document.getElementById('checkbox').addEventListener('change', function (event) {
  document.getElementById('val').innerHTML = event.target.checked;
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" value="input">
</div>
<div>
  <label tabindex="0">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" style="display:none;">
    checkbox: <span id="val">false</span>
  </label>
</div>
<span tabindex="0">span with tabindex</span>
```

(The JavaScript code just allows to see that clicking on the label properly (un)checks the checkbox.)

Comment: a label isn't a layer, nor a input, its just a shematic element

Comment: @UnskilledFreak Why would that make `tabindex` not work on it? I've added a `<span>` to my code to better demonstrate the issue.

Comment: tabindex is "prehistoric" to jump from input to input without the use of a mouse, so WHY would u want to jump to an label? Whats the reason?

Comment: `tabindex` is still *very* important today for accessibility. Additionally, it is still [part of the HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#sequential-focus-navigation-and-the-tabindex-attribute). Lastly, `tabindex` is [a **valid** attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) for `label` elements.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

> Why doesn't tabindex make the label focusable?

**Short Answer**:

1. Label is focusable.
2. TabIndex won't make any difference.
3. Welcome to the world of browser/agent inconsistencies.

**tl;dr;**

The `label` [(Ref)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#htmllabelelement) element is very much focusable. Its DOM Interface is `HTMLLabelElement` which derives from `HTMLElement` [(Ref)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#htmlelement) which in turn implements `GlobalEventHandlers` [(Ref)](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#globaleventhandlers) and hence exposes the `focus()` method and `onfocus` event handler.

The reason you are unable to get hold of proper specification / reference document for `label`s focus behaviour, is because you might have been looking at HTML5 Specs. Interestingly, HTML5 refs do not state anything relating to that, which adds to the confusion.

This is mentioned in the HTML 4.01 Ref here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

Specifically near the end of section 17.9.1 and just before 17.10:

> When a LABEL element receives focus, it passes the focus on to its
>   associated control.

Also, elsewhere (*I am unable to get hold of that part of the ref*) I have read that it depends on the implementing agent. (*Don't take my word for that, am not too sure*).

However, what it means is that when you `focus` a `label` (or a `label` received a `focus`), that `focus` is passed on to its associated labeleable control. This will not result in two different `focus`es, but one `focus` on the `input` (in your case a checkbox). Because of this behaviour, `tabindex` property cannot play a role.

There is also a test suite by W3C for website accessibility (WAAG) here: http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0102/0102-ONFOCUS-ONBLUR-LABEL.html which, discusses the implementation of `onfocus` and `onblur` for a `label`. Ideally a *keyboard or an assistive technology that emulates the keyboard* should implement this. But...

This is where the browser inconsistencies play their role.

This can be demonstrated by this example. Check the following snippet in different browsers. (I have tested it against IE-11, GC-39 and FF-34. All of them behave differently.)

1. Click the button "*Focus Label*"
2. It should focus the label, then pass the focus and highlight its associated checkbox outline in blue.
3. Chrome-v39 works. IE-v11 it doesn't (somehow html and body do respond to :focus). FF-v34 it works.

Talking about browser inconsistencies, try using the "access key" <kbd>L</kbd>. Some browsers will focus the checkbox whereas some will click it i.e. pass the action to it.

Here is a **fiddle** to test it: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ff0xds4z/2/

Here is a **snippet**:

```js
label = $("label").first();
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    label.focus();
});
```

```css
* { margin: 8px; }
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }
:focus {
    outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txt" type="text" value="input" /><br />
<label for="chk" accesskey="L">Checkbox: </label>
<input id="chk" type="checkbox" /><br />
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Focus Label" />
```

Hope that clears up your doubts.

.

---

### Your problem:

Now `focus`sing (*sic*) on your original problem of not being able to focus a label, because you want to style a checkbox differently by placing an icon kind of thing in its place.

In order to do that, one option for you is to ***not*** hide it completely by doing a `display:none;`. Rather, make it 1x1 pixel and shove it under your icon. This way it will still receive focus naturally and yet be effectively hidden.

For example, if your icons are a *checkmark* and a *cross*, then change the position of the checkbox and make the icons out of `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements on the label. That will cause the checkbox to still receive focus, and make the icon respond to that. That will give the apparent illusion of the icon taking the focus.

***Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/v0vxcw77/***

***Snippet***:

```css
div.chkGroup { position: relative; }
input#chk {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px; height: 1px;
    margin: 0; margin-top: 4px; outline: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent; background-color: transparent;
}
label::before {
    content: '\2714';
    position: relative;
    width: 18px; height: 18px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-right: 8px; padding: 2px;
    display: inline-block; 
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
input#chk:checked + label::before {
    content: '\2716';
}
input#chk:focus + label::before {
    border: 1px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<input id="txt" type="text" value="input" /><br /><br />
<div class="chkGroup">
    <input id="chk" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="chk" accesskey="L">Checkbox</label>
</div>
```

.

Comment: I had my suspicions about label transferring focus to the input, but didn't know for sure. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Thanks also for the suggested solution, but I'm going with a different tack. Your solution requires putting an opaque background behind the icon, which is pretty inconvenient. Instead, I'm automatically adding a "replacement" after the checkbox. With `tabindex` and some scripting, I'm able to transfer the appropriate events to the input (dispatch them on it). Since I'm using AngularJS, it's pretty easy to encapsulate this in an `input` directive.

Comment: @hon2a: Yup. That is a pretty neat solution as well. You can   place a replacement on the checkbox itself and handle it. Best wishes.

Comment: Just wondering, what is an example of a browser/platform that doesn’t check the checkbox in the first snippet when pressing Alt+Shift+l?

Comment: Regarding the first snippet again, it looks like IE-11.0.8 is following [Focus Management](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#focus-management) (as of 2014-12-19). Adding `tabindex` to the `<label/>` results in the label fulfilling the conditions and suddenly the button *does* cause focus to change ;-). Maybe the focus chaining is absent from the HTML5 drafts because the behavior is left to be implementation dependent, but it looks like IE *is* respecting the draft…

Answer (score 4):

Since this old post is one of the top google results for **html label tabindex** I want to add my very simple working solution. As @Abhitalks mentioned in the accepted answer, the focus of a label is passed to it's associated control. So to bypass this behavior, just add a `tabindex` to the label and use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in a `focus` `EventListener`.

@Heretic Monkey kind of had the right idea in his answer but you don't need a wrapper element to achieve this. You will, however, need to manually forward any required keystrokes (like spacebar) through.

For example:

```js
'use strict';

let field = document.getElementById('hidden-file-chooser');
let label = document.querySelector('label[for=hidden-file-chooser]');

// prevent focus passing
label.addEventListener('focus', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
});

// activate using spacebar
label.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
  if (event.keyCode == 32) {
    field.click();
  }
});
```

```css
#hidden-file-chooser {
  display: none;
}

input[type=text] {
  display: block;
  width: 20rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

label[for=hidden-file-chooser] {
  display: inline-block;
  background: deepskyblue;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.5rem 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Click here and start tabbing through ...">

<input id="hidden-file-chooser" type="file">
<label for="hidden-file-chooser" tabindex="0"> Select a File </label>

<input type="text" placeholder="... then shift+tab to go back.">
```

P.S: I used `input[type=file]` in my example because that's what I was working on when I ran across this issue. The same principles apply to any input type.

Comment: Just wanted to leave a comment to specifically thank you @Besworks for your answer. Just what I needed! The only thing left for me to figure out is how to prevent it from still stopping on the hidden checkbox while tabbing through the inputs. But at least my label (styled to look like a menu button) is properly showing focus styles now!!

Comment: Update: Adding `tabstop="-1"` to the checkbox prevents it from being focussed on. So that it's passed over while tabbing through the inputs. Also noticed that the spacebar would scroll the page, so I added an `e.preventDefault()` to the keydown (not keyup) event tracking the spacebar input. I also added a keyup for the enter key (keyCode == 13). Everything works perfectly now!

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: The following was a misreading of the spec:

> <del>Looking that [the full
>   specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex),
>   you'll see that there is something called [tabindex focus
>   flag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#specially-focusable),
>   which defines if the `tabindex` attribute will actually make the field
>   "tabbable". The `label` element is missing from that list of suggested
>   elements.</del>
>
> <del>But then again, so is the `span` element, so go figure :).</del>

<del>That said, y</del>You can make the label text focusable by wrapping the whole thing in an another element, or using some JavaScript to force the issue. Unfortunately, wrapping (here in an anchor) can men a fair amount of extra work in CSS and JS to get working like a normal `label` element.

```js
document.getElementById('checkbox').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  document.getElementById('val').innerHTML = event.target.checked;
});
document.getElementsByClassName('label')[0].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.target.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].click();
  event.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementsByClassName('label')[0].addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  if ((event.key || event.which || event.keyCode) === 32) {
    event.target.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].click();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
.label,
.label:visited,
.label:hover,
.label:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" value="input">
</div>
<div>
  <a class="label" href="#">
    <label tabindex="0">
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" style="display:none;">checkbox: <span id="val">false</span>
    </label>
  </a>
</div>
<span tabindex="0">span with tabindex</span>
```

Comment: The spec section you note lists the elements that browser vendors should set the focus flag by default (ie: no `tabindex` attribute required for them to be focusable)

Comment: Sorry for not reading the linked documentation before. As far as I can see, @steveax is right. The documentation states that some of the elements should have the _tabindex focus flag_ set by default (and `label` is not among them), but otherwise that flag should be set in the presence of `tabindex` attribute. So, I have to un-accept the answer.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan You might want to edit your answer, as the information at the beginning is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

As previous posters said: 
**Label focus always goes directly to the input element.**

Quite an annoyance if somebody has fancy (but fake) checkboxes, hiding the original ones, with an actual focus for keyboard navigation nowhere to be seen.

**best solution I can think of: javascript.**

Style-away the actual focus, in favor of a fake one:

```
    input[type=checkbox]:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
    .pseudo-focus {
        outline: 2px solid blue;
    }
```

and watch for changes on the (in many scenarios visibly hidden) original checkbox:

```
    $('input[type=checkbox')
        .focus( function() {
            $(this).closest('label').addClass('pseudo-focus');
        })
        .blur( function() {
            $(this).closest('label').removeClass('pseudo-focus');    
        });
```

Full [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/frankee/23t53sp4/).

Comment: Inputs hidden by regular means (like `display: none`) cannot receive focus. Your JSFiddle doesn't actually hide anything and thus doesn't show this.

Comment: I corrected the fiddle, got the wrong version somehow. Now it shows, that you can virtually tab also through the label. |   True, the input must not be hidden, only visibly by means like `left:-999px;position: absolute;` or similar.

Answer (score -3):

For input type radio or checkbox:

```
opacity: 0;
height: 0;
width: 0;
min-height: 0;
line-height: 0;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0 none;
```

and the Js above does the trick sweetly.